# Split string to numbers in Lua

Tags: lua

I've a problem with splitting this:

```
x = "-301 1021"
```

to this

```
x = -301
y = 1021
```

In C++ this is easier but I really don't know how to do it in Lua. I tried do it like

```
string1 .. string[i]
```

@Edit
   I've made it like this but now it doesn't get values which are negative

```
 for coordinate in ActualCoords:gmatch("%w+") do 
     table.insert(coordinates, coordinate)
 end
        x = coordinates[1];
        x = tonumber(x);
        z = coordinates[2];
        z = tonumber(z);
```

Comment: `x = '-301 1021'
x,y = x:match'(%S+)%s+(%S+)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is regular:

```
restults = {};
for m in str:gmatch("[^%s]+") do
    results[#results+1] = m+0;
end
```

If input is irregular, meaning you need to verify that its not random things separated by spaces, you need to make a more complex pattern, eg.

```
"[%deE.-]+"
```

Comment: Your gmatch() argument helped. I made loop with simpliest way (at least for me)

    
        for coordinate in ActualCoords:gmatch("[^%s]+") do 
             table.insert(coordinates, coordinate);
     end

Comment: @Pyrol You may need to coerce to number (the `+0`)

Comment: `%S` is exactly equivalent to `[^%s]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = "-301 1021"
x,y = s:match("(%S+)%s+(%S+)")
x,y = tonumber(x), tonumber(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html) for such parsing tasks.

```
local lpeg = assert(require"lpeg")
local R, S = lpeg.R, lpeg.S

local integer = (S'+-'^-1 * R("09")^1) / tonumber
local space = S(" \t")^0

local x, y = lpeg.match((integer * space)^1, "-301 1021")
print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

or try this

```
local s  = "-301 1021 -300 1022 -20 -1000"
local coord = {}
for x,y in s:gmatch("(-?%d+).-(-?%d+)") do
 coord[#coord+1] = { x=tonumber(x), y=tonumber(y) }
end

print( coord[1].x, coord[1].y)
print( coord[2].x, coord[2].y)
print( coord[3].x, coord[3].y)
```